# Simulating a click with jQuery on "select2" dropdown does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I try to simulate a click with jQuery on a select2 (https://select2.github.io/select2/) dropdown menu, but the click event does not work...

**What I tried**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  let rightElement = $('ul.select2-results__options li:nth-child(2)');
  if (rightElement.length) {
    rightElement.click();
  }
}, 3000)
```

The element exists, but the click does not fires. I´m using this dropdown with the official "WP Job Manager" for Wordpress to filter jobs with categorys and I try to preselect a category on page load.

Do you have any idea why the click event not fires?

Comment: Check if `rightElement ` is a HTML element or an Array?

Comment: Is a HTML element.

Comment: If it's a HTML element, how are you getting the `length` of it? Please check my answer.

Comment: Don't simulate clicks. Use Select2's built in methods for programmatically selecting values.

Comment: @Rory. Thanks. How could I do it?

Comment: `$("#element").select2("val", "CA");`

Comment: It´s not working. I think because the plugin is loading content with ajax after the user click to a list item...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [triggering](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event?

```js
rightElement.trigger('click')
```

Here is a plain JavaScript function that accomplishes the same thing.

```js
triggerEvent(document.'ul.select2-results__options li:nth-child(2)', 'click');

function triggerEvent(el, eventName) {
  let event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the if condition. `length` property of an html element will always be `undefined`. And that's why your event is not getting triggered. Do it like this:-

```
setTimeout(function() {
  let rightElement = $('ul.select2-results__options li:nth-child(2)');
  if (rightElement) {
    rightElement.click();
  }
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Also not works..but a console.log statement got fired.

Comment: No, nothing :-)